# What's the difference between an installer and a facility in Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between IWindsorInstaller and AbstractFacility in Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199211/difference-between-iwindsorinstaller-and-abstractfacility-in-castle)

I've been using castle windsor as my IoC container on a bunch of MVC projects but I'm still not sure what the difference is between an installer and a facility.

I was wondering if anyone could provide an explanation as to what the difference is between the two, and when I might want to use one of the other.

Comment: I agree... voted to close rather than delete though because the question is framed differently